# Show particular record as last value while loop

Tags: php, mysql

The table records are

```
tag       enabled

paypal      1
bank        1
creditcard  1
COD         1
```

and my query is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM payment_type WHERE enabled = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $data['tag'];
}
```

Here I want to show creditcard as last value for some reasons. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: see **[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30f62/2)**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM payment_type WHERE enabled = '1'
        Order By case when tag <> 'creditcard' then 0 else 1 end;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` to make an individual sort order

```
SELECT * FROM payment_type 
WHERE enabled = '1'
order by case when tag = 'creditcard' 
              then 1
              else 2
         end
```